# Powershell - Is there any way to sort unique objects in ForEach-Object?

Tags: powershell, sitecore, powershell-4.0

I have an array where I need to sort the unique values, and duplicates, and show that to `Show-ListView`. I am a beginner in making PowerShell scripts, especially for **Sitecore** so my code is going to look very bad, but bare with me.

**Here is the code so far:**

```
@($rootItem) + @($rootItem.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $currentItem = $_
        Get-ItemField -Item $currentItem -ReturnType Field -Name "*" `
            | ForEach-Object{
                $NewValue = $value.Split(",")
                ForEach($i in $NewValue) {
                if($PSItem.Value -match $i -and $PSItem.Name.Contains("Tags")){
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        "Name"=$currentItem.DisplayName
                        "ItemId"=$currentItem.ID
                        "FieldName"=$_.Name
                        "ItemPath" = Get-MediaUrl($currentItem)
                    }
Copy-Item -Path $currentItem.ItemPath -Destination $folderToMove.Paths.FullPath;
                }
                }
                
            } 
} | Show-ListView
```

The `$rootItem` is just a folder where those items exist (sitecore/Media Library/Images). Now I need to copy those items to another folder. That is actually not a problem, since in **Sitecore** it does not copy duplicate values, but in `Show-ListView` it shows them.

To describe you the problem I am encountering, I basically want to get **Images** that have certain **tags**. When you input one tag, everything is fine, but when I input set of tags, for example `stackoverflow,sitecore`, it shows one item that has these two tags, two times.

Is there any way for me to **sort** `ForEach-Object`. I now there is `Sort-Object -Unique`, but I do not know if that would help me.

Comment: sort will accept piped input.

Comment: Change the last line from `} | Show-ListView` to `} |Sort-Object -Unique ItemID | Show-ListView`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you very much! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Like @MathiasR.Jessen said in the comments, basically I had to add the `|Sort-Object -Unique ItemID | Show-ListView` at the end of the code.

**The working code looks like this now:**

```
@($rootItem) + @($rootItem.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $currentItem = $_
        Get-ItemField -Item $currentItem -ReturnType Field -Name "*" `
            | ForEach-Object{
                $NewValue = $value.Split(",")
                ForEach($i in $NewValue) {
                if($PSItem.Value -match $i -and $PSItem.Name.Contains("Tags")){
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        "Name"=$currentItem.DisplayName
                        "ItemId"=$currentItem.ID
                        "FieldName"=$_.Name
                        "ItemPath" = Get-MediaUrl($currentItem)
                    }
Copy-Item -Path $currentItem.ItemPath -Destination $folderToMove.Paths.FullPath;
                }
                }
                
            } 
} | Sort-Object -Unique ItemID | Show-ListView
```